What makes people interested in charge density wave in recent years?
This is a question regarding the current research status in charge density wave (CDW) related materials.
From my naive understanding, CDW shares many similarities with superconductor, which has been a mature field. I wonder, what are the outstanding questions remaining in the CDW field that most people care about? Or in other words, what makes it a long-lasting player among condensed matter researchers? (Unlike superconductors where mechanism for high-Tc has always been a mystery)

I think firstly the mechanisms of CDW are still under debate and new mechanisms are being proposed, see for example https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.77.165135. Secondly, the coexistence and competition between CDW and superconductivity is an interesting subject and may be helpful to reveal the mechanism of high-Tc superconductivity.
